# open program instead system properties - windows 7

Tags: windows-7, properties, system-info

I want to open another program (like everest) to show system information instead the default windows 7 system information window when right-clicking on computer

[image]

Is there a way to replace the action on the "Properties Item" on the context menu on Windows 7?

Comment: According to this link http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/add-shortcuts-in-my-computer-context-menu/  You may want a particularly obscure registry key, but you might need to be administrator to do it and even then I don't think it'd edit it for properties for example but I haven't tested it. But definitely the standard context menu edits e.g. here http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/  don't apply to that Computer menu

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Add A **Context Menu Entry**... **Search On Google** How to Add Context Menu Entry in Windows OS

Comment: welcome by the way screenshot is in which language???

Comment: @user962284 Actually no it doesn't answer your question. It's a workaround. You asked about how to work with the Computer menu. I just tested the File menu and Folder menu here which is a link editing the context menu http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/   And none of these things affect the Computer context menu at all. Now it's possible you found a link that shows you the registry key that does it, but it doesn't just pop up -not the first link anyway- with Googling what vishal recommended, so I suggest that you share it.